# Why can't save file without tab key?

Tags: tab-characters

Configuration in my `.vimrc`:

```
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```

I have edit a file which contain `tab`,saved and reopen to have a look at it with `set list`,the tab key saved,why `set expandtab` can't convert `tab` into 4 spaces automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why set expandtab can't convert tab into 4 spaces automatically?

Because it's not supposed to. What `expandtab` does, it inserts spaces when you *press* tab key (but <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> still inserts a tab).

Use `:h :retab` to convert *existing* tabs to spaces.